# How to setup HoloEverywhere on ADT?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to use [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) on ADT(Eclipse).
What I make wrong?

1. I'm download [that](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)
2. File > Import > Existing Code into Workspace
3. I'm download [that](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)
4. 2 Step again(library is disabled).
5. I'm trying to change theme

   android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock"

But Eclipse says

> No resource found that maches the given name

If I'm trying replace extends from

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.sherlock.SListActivity {
```

I'm getting

> com.WazaBe cannot be resolved as type

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADT r-17 and up you may need to move a copy of the holo everywhere library into a `libs/` folder(that you will have to create) in your workspace.

Comment: Have you imported the library into you activity?

Comment: How? I can't use com.WazaBe.* package.

Comment: I am probably getting something wrong but, `import com.WazaBe.*`

Comment: OK. I'm copy `com.WazaBe.*` to `src/`  but Eclipse marked a lot of errors on this package.